# Symfony2 - createForm called with custom form type's name/alias throws "Could not load type" exception

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I was reading the documentation on defining forms as services and followed the guide. but I keep running into the following error:

> Could not load type "submission"

here is my `services.yml`

```
services:
    submission.form.type.submission:
        class:Awesome\SubmissionBundle\Form\Type\SubmissionType
        tags:
            - {name: form.type, alias: submission}
```

here is my form

```
<?php

namespace Awesome\SubmissionBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SubmissionType extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('contact', 'text')
            ->add('message', 'textarea')
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ;
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'submission';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) 
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Awesome\SubmissionBundle\Entity\Submission',
        ));
    }
}
```

In any controller I can `$this->get('submission.form.type.submission')` without errors.

**But why can't I do `$this->createForm('submission', $submission)`** ? as is dictated by the official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services).

**UPDATE**
I have made some progress. I found that if I put my services configuration in symfony's main `config.yml` rather than the bundles `services.yml` The code starts to work. This is perplexing but I guess it leads to me posting just how I'm loading the bundle's `services.yml`.

Here is my bundle's registered compiler pass:

```
<?php

namespace Awesome\SubmissionBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class SubmissionCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $relative_path = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('..', '..', 'Resources', 'config'));
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . $relative_path));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

}
```

and regardless of where I place my configuration the command `container:debug submission.form.type.submission` always gives the same output which seems fine to me:

```
[container] Information for service submission.form.type.submission
Service Id       submission.form.type.submission
Class            Awesome\SubmissionBundle\Form\Type\SubmissionType
Tags
    - form.type                      (alias: submission)
Scope            container
Public           yes
Synthetic        no
Required File    -
```

Comment: The mismatch in namespaces is a copy/paste/edit failure of yours, right? The class namespace `Awesome\SubmissionBundle\Form\Type;` does not match `Guide\SubmissionBundle\Form\Type\SubmissionType` in your service definition. Did you clear your cache?

Comment: @nifr yes I've edited.

Comment: I have edited the code in your question. please make sure you have no tabs in your code. Further i recommend you stick to the symfony2 [coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) i.e. for method declarations. Does `this->createForm($this->get('submission.form.type.submission'), $submission);` work?

Comment: @nifr Didn't realise my IDE was laying tabs instead. thanks for spotting that! And yes that does work. But I still wonder why the documented way doesn't?

Comment: What you posted should work.  Delete your cache.

Comment: @Cerad I have `cache:clear` both production and development environments still no luck.

Comment: @Cerad I've made some progress. see the update!

Comment: I've found that deleting cache with the console doesn't work (even with success message) in some development environments (vagrant boxes), so a `rm -rf app/cache/*` is just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher I tried that, no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is within loading the services.yml in a CompilerPass.
The loading of the "form.type" tags is happening also in a CompilerPass (`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\FormPass`). So your CompilerPass is executed after the form CompilerPass and it won't find your form type.

If you are using the Symfony Standard Edition and you have created your bundle with the [generator command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html) you will have an `AwesomeSubmissionExtension` class in your DependencyInjection folder which is intended for loading service files.

The following code is the changed extension code for loading yaml files. (The default is to XmlFileLoader)

```
namespace Awesome\SubmissionBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AwesomeSubmissionExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another issue:
It's `data_class`, not `data`

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) 
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Awesome\SubmissionBundle\Entity\Submission',
    ));
}
```